# How search in php mysql query in where condition column_name='bolt 1/2 inch'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in a db table that contains 'bolt 1/2 inch'

i got hanged when passing forward slash in the variable. If there is no slash then it code is working fine.

```
$par_stockDescription = 'bolt 1/2 inch'
$description = mysql_real_escape_string($par_stockDescription);

$sql_getStockId = "SELECT stock_id,units FROM table_name WHERE description ='".$description ."';

$result_stockId =db_query($sql_getStockId);
$arr_stockId = db_fetch($result_stockId);
echo  $arr_stockId['stock_id'];
```

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0. You should use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: can u please tell me what exactly i have to modify in the above code

Comment: Read more on PDO: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php (this page tells something about preparing statements, but it is useful to read more about it and really understand what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

Your string quota are not correct use this:

```
$sql_getStockId = "SELECT stock_id,units FROM table_name WHERE description ='".$description ."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to the following

```
$sql_getStockId = "SELECT stock_id,units FROM table_name WHERE description ='".$description ."'";
```

Comment: thats not an issue... have to pass '/' in the middle of the string. so how to do that

Answer (score 0):

This should be your query:

```
$sql_getStockId = "SELECT stock_id,units FROM table_name WHERE description ='".$description ."'";
```

Also [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) has been deprecated consider mysqli or pdo

Comment: tell me what exactly i have to modify in the above code